# Apache redirect to tomcat OR default DocumentRoot

Tags: apache, tomcat

I am trying to redirect the http request to tomcat or default DocumentRoot base on the url condition.

Example:

```
IF url contains /css/ then serving the file from /var/www
else
redirect to tomcat using JKMount
```

Here is the configuration in the httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www
     RewriteEngine on 
     LogLevel debug
     RewriteLogLevel 3
     RewriteLog logs/apache-mod_rewrite

     RewriteRule ^/css/(.*)$ /var/www/css/$1 [L]

     RewriteCond $1 !^portal
     RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /portal/?user=YES [L,PT]
     JkMount  /* failover
</VirtualHost>
```

When try to request to http://www.example.com it get redirect to tomcat and serve the page correctly.

However when try to request http://www.example.com/css/sample.css, apache return error 404.
May I know is it not possible to have condition forwarding to either default DocumentRoot or tomcat?
Thanks in advanced.